# fUtilLib & fAllocator for PhysX 2.7

Tags: c++, physx

does anybody know where I can find the lib/source that declares the fUtilLib & fAllocator identifiers?

The code I am working on is from 2007-2009, so it's a rather old code. The PhysX SDK in use is 2.7.3 currently. *(I have a suspicion that I need a specific version such as 2.7.0)*

```
    HMODULE sd=LoadLibrary((LPCTSTR)"PhysXCore.dll");
    df=(ffd)GetProcAddress(sd,"NpCreatePhysicsSDK");

    NxGetUtilLib=(fUtilLib)GetProcAddress(sd,"NpGetUtilLib");
    NxGetPhysicsSDKAllocator=(fAllocator)GetProcAddress(sd,"NpGetPhysicsSDKAllocator");
```

Comment: That's horrible code. Anyhow, you should be able to find the function signature for these functions in the headers that typically come with DLLs.

Comment: Again with the opinions, this place never changes. If you don't have an answer, why waste your time... if they were in the headers, I would have probably noticed it.